# Adding an "Event" with date type in the vector

Tags: java, date, vector

I cannot add the event due to the date I inputted. I am not sure of which pattern it should be.

```
Event h1 = new Event(Tue Dec 13 00:00:00 CST 2022, "New Year's Day", "New Year's Day", "Holiday");
vEvents.add(h1);
```

This is the event class

```
public Event(Date d, String t, String de, String ty){
        this.date = new Date(d.getTime());
        this.title = t;
        this.desc = de;
        this.type = ty;
    }
```

Comment: passing "Tue Dec 13 00:00:00 CST 2022" directly sould give you some error

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
Tue Dec 13 00:00:00 CST 2022
```

isn't a `Date`.  It's not even valid Java - it's not wrapped in a `String` of any kind, and will cause compilation errors.

If you're looking to pass in a specific day, take a look at the [`Calendar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class, or better yet, [Joda Time](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time).

Answer (score 0):

You should not send a `Date` object like a `String` (Tue Dec 13 00:00:00 CST 2022), instead get a `Calendar` instance, set the date there and send the `Date` from there.

Little example:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2022);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DECEMBER);
c.set(Calendar.DATE, 13);
Event h1 = new Event(c.getTime(), "New Year's Day", "New Year's Day", "Holiday");
vEvents.add(h1);
```

In order to not rewrite all the `Calendar` bunch of code, you can create an utility method in order to get a `Date` instance:

```
public class Utils {

    public static Date getDate(int day, int month, int year) {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month - 1);
        c.set(Calendar.DATE, day);
        return c.getTime();
    }
}

//now calling this utility method in your code
Event h1 = new Event(Utils.getDate(13, 12, 2022), "New Year's Day", "New Year's Day", "Holiday");
vEvents.add(h1);
```

As a more advanced (and real world application) solution, you should move to use Joda Time as stated in Makoto's answer.